# How to set Skydrive folder location on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I already have my Skydrive files on disk.  How do I set the Skydrive folder location in Windows 8?

Edit: to be more clear, I have just installed Windows 8 and my previous Skydrive files were already on my PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you need to install the Skydrive desktop application to sync files.  The Metro app doesn't sync files.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the [official FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/windows-app-faq):

> Can I change the name or location of my SkyDrive folder after it's
>   created?
>
> **No.** If you use Windows Explorer to rename or move your SkyDrive
>   folder, SkyDrive will stop working.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear in the question.  I have edited it to make it clearer.  I didn't want to change the location of the files, I have just installed Win8 and I wanted to set the location of the skydrive folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the skydrive desktop application installed and you want to move the folder, you may run into trouble if your skydrive is the same user id as your windows log in. You won't be able to disconnect your account, which is the easy way to reconfigure your file path - disconnect and reconnect the account from the desktop application. If you need to move the folder, quit the desktop app from the systray, delete the folder and favorite link from the sidebar, and then relaunch the desktop application. It will tell you it can't find the folder, and allow you to reconnect to your account, complete with an option to set the desktop path.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy :D
Just do everything as in link below.
http://maxshifman.com/2012/08/30/move-microsoft-skydrive-folder-location-without-re-downloading-all-files/

Comment: please do your best writing the relevant link contents instead of simply putting it on your answer. if the link ever gets broken so does your whole answer.