# How do I change the SkyDrive default folder in Windows

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

How do I change the default location of SkyDrive files in windows 8?

The Skydrive Modern UI app in Windows 8 shows a default folder named `[pc-name skydrive]` and I can't find where it is.

I found the following question, but it doesn't give me enough details:

[How to set Skydrive folder location on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/467019/how-to-set-skydrive-folder-location-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set this when you run the skydrive app for the first time. Or you can unlink and relink, then you can choose the folder you want after you signed in.

http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-skydrive-sync-documents-pictures-144202

> The first time you run the SkyDrive application, you’re asked to sign in with your Microsoft account—use the same account you sign into Windows 8 with, of course—and choose a location in the file system to which to sync your SkyDrive-based folders and their contents. The default location is C:\Users[User-name]\SkyDrive, but you’re free to locate this folder anyway.

If you're after finding where it is in explorer, from the above quote it would be `C:\Users\[User-name]\SkyDrive` by default.

---

As the answer linked in your question says you cannot change the folder after this.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/skydrive/windows-app-faq

> Can I change the name or location of my SkyDrive folder after it's created?
>   No. If you use Windows Explorer to rename or move your SkyDrive folder, SkyDrive will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7, you have to unlink the onedrive (using right-click + settings in the system tray icon) and then you will get the option to re-enable the one drive where you can choose the default folder. it will take less than a min to do this.