# Changing SkyDrive Default Location to a Network Location (W8.1)

Tags: onedrive, windows-8.1

**Update:** This issue is due to the use of any non-local location for the SkyDrive folder. I've currently worked around this by using a local folder, but this has not resolved the original problem.

I am trying to change the location where SkyDrive is located in Windows 8.1. This is the newly integrated SkyDrive, and not a downloadable client. There are a couple of similar questions on this site, but they pertain to Windows 8 and 8.1 Preview:

- [Changing the SkyDrive default path in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/612868/changing-the-skydrive-default-path-in-windows-8-1) (Windows 8.1 Preview)
- [How do I change the SkyDrive default folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/492055/how-do-i-change-the-skydrive-default-folder-in-windows) (Windows 8)

The SkyDrive folder is a system folder in 8.1, and like other system folders, has a Location tab in its properties that theoretically lets you change its location. I was able to do this with other system folders such as Downloads and Pictures, but there is an error when I try to change this for SkyDrive.

**Edit:** The location that causes this error is a mapped network drive. The error does not occur when trying to move SkyDrive to another location on the same drive. There are no permission restrictions on the mapped network drive.

**Edit #2:** This is the method I followed that produced the error:

A screenshot of the error can be found here

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this or have any information on this?

Comment: The answer I wrote http://superuser.com/questions/612868/changing-the-skydrive-default-path-in-windows-8-1/643792#643792 only applies to the RTM build.  Besides it wasn't possible to move it in the Preview build.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was pertaining to the app version of SkyDrive. I was hoping there was a work around since the Location dialog exists under Properties and isn't disabled as it should be if this is not an option. Also I was not prompted for a SkyDrive login, this seems to have happened automatically when I used a Live account login when setting up 8.1. I'll see what I can do about resetting this then, since the official page says it can only be set on first startup ...

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the answer you gave in the linked thread (and described in that article) is what I tried the first time, which resulted in this error.

Comment: I have clarified the original question with more accurate information.

Comment: which drive is R:\?

Comment: It is an NTFS mapped network drive on a local NAS. I am able to browse/edit this drive without authentication, and otherwise interact with it.

Comment: Same with a network path like `\\server\share\username`. Seems like MS doesn't want you to map a SkyDrive to a network location. If you did that, then it could be used in cojunction with Offline Files (and that might cause problems?). The info "[..] or an other computer on the network" is misleading in any case. You could try syminks and junctions also, and see how it works with them.

Comment: What happens if you select a folder on that drive, instead of the drive itself?

Comment: I also verified with SkyDrive Client that use of symlinks (pointing to network locations) doesn't work. The files never get synced.

Comment: The error occurs whether it's the base drive or a folder on that drive. Thanks to others for trying alternative methods of pointing at network locations.

Comment: @techie007 Please read the question before commenting with a link that doesn't solve the problem, and is already linked to in the OP for reference.