# Where is the SkyDrive folder located in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

In the normal Windows SkyDrive application, the SkyDrive folder is defaults to `C:\Users\<username>\SkyDrive`.

SkyDrive comes preinstalled on Windows 8, but I notice that the SkyDrive folder isn't where it used to be.  **So, where is it?**

I've tried searching online, but to no avail.  Also, I searched my hard-drive for "SkyDrive," but 0 results were found (!?).

Comment: I have seen [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/467019/how-to-set-skydrive-folder-location-on-windows-8?rq=1), which states that the folder location for the metro app cannot be changed.. but it does not actually mention where the folder is!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SkyDrive does not come pre-installed on Windows 8.

The SkyDrive Modern UI application is not a regular SkyDrive client; it does not interact with the regular filesystem.

If you want to use SkyDrive from the desktop, you will still need to install the [desktop client](https://apps.live.com/skydrive).

Comment: Erm, so you are telling me there's no way to view my SkyDrive files from Windows, outside the Metro App, unless I install the non-Metro version of SkyDrive?

Comment: @BlueRaja: Correct.  Windows 8 does not include a desktop SkyDrive client.  (although Office 2013 does)

Comment: Metro-y, cellphone-y apps are like that. If you want computer interaction, you need to install computer programs. Apps for the most part are **Program Lite**, almost but not quite unlike the real thing. And often the storage is "out there" which means no local storage and no working with them with no connection.

Answer (score 3):

SkyDrive isnt installed on Windows 8, but if you copy a file on the desktop it will be synchronized in the cloud (skydrive.hotmail.com).

But the files are not stored locally, SkyDrive on Windows 8 displays the list of folder and files online in the cloud.

There is a hidden folder called C: \ SkyDriveTemp \ which is used for "traffic", upload and download files, but you can not use it as storage for the content of it is temporary and controlled by the program in a "different".

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. The last sentence is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

The ModernUI version of SkyDrive doesn't store the files locally - which is a pain if you want to use (for example) an image from your SkyDrive as your profile picture, desktop background, etc.

The solution to this is either install the desktop version as well, or if on Windows 8 RT, download the files you want to use outside of SkyDrive on to your file system:

1. Browse to the files or files you want to download
2. Right click/Swipe down on the files, which will outline them and add a "tick" overlay on the file, and display the task bar.
3. Select "Download" from the task bar, which will allow you to select the local folder you want to add them to.

Alternatively you can select the files, and "Share" them with some apps from the Share charm.

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming release of Windows 8.1, a SkyDrive folder will be pre-installed and included in the path you specified. It can be used in the current Preview of Windows 8.1.